# When I transfer my Iphone Xcode project/files to another Mac the Simulator doesn't run it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, project, simulator

I made a project in Xcode that is a logic game for the Iphone.

When I run the project on my own Macbook it runs perfectly fine.

However when I copy the files over to a flash drive or send the files in an e-mail and try to run the project on another computer, the project successfully builds but it doesn't run (it shows a black screen, then after a few seconds it goes to the 'home screen' of the simulator).

What could be the problem? I made sure the Simulator was the same for both computers. (4.2)

If it helps to know, my project has a bunch of .xib files, and a lot of .png files.

Comment: Try debugger .. to see at what point of your code its crashing(I am sure its crashing in the first or second view controllers of your app) .. believe me debugger helps a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Build -> Clean, Build -> Clean all targets and touching the source files?
If this doesn't help, try using the Debugger, as already suggested, found under Run -> Debugger..

I woudl post this as a comment, but I have no rights to do so yet.